# the page has the html element or hasn't - objective c

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode, uiwebview

i try to find the web page has the html element or not. i use if condition, like;

```
    if([webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return document.getElementById('txtOgR_no');"] != nil)
    {...}
```

how can i check is there a element in page named "txtOgr_No" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns a boolean value

```
return !!document.getElementById('txtOgR_no');
```

And by 'named' I guess you mean 'have an id of ..' as names are only used for form elements.